# Linux - IO exceptions when running jar file through shell script

Tags: java, linux, shell

I am using Debain 8.0 - jessie (64 bit).

I am getting IO exceptions when I try to run a jar file, from outside its directory, through a shell script.

Directory: "/home/rscedit"

Files: "data (directory)"  "run.sh (file)"  "Webserver.jar (file)"

When I try to run "run.sh" from anywhere besides "/home/rscedit", I am facing IO exceptions in my jar file.

But if I try to run "run.sh" from "/home/rscedit", it runs perfectly fine.

I want to run my shell script at startup, so I should be able to run my shell script from outside "/home/rscedit" right?

Shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar -Xmx20480m /home/rscedit/Webserver.jar
read –n1
```

The error I get when executing my shell script

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ./data/log/ipn.log.lck
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:459)
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:326)
        at org.displee.utilities.logging.LogFactory.loadFileLogger(LogFactory.java:44)
        at org.displee.utilities.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:19)
```

LogFactory.java

```
package org.displee.utilities.logging;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class LogFactory {

    private static final String FORMAT = "%1$td-%1$tm-%1$tY %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s - %5$s%6$s%n";

    private static final Map<String, Logger> MAP = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        try {
            loadFileLogger("ipn", "./data/log/ipn.log");
            loadFileLogger("error", "./data/log/error.log");

            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("console");
            logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
            ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
            ch.setFormatter(new ConsoleFormatter());
            ch.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            logger.addHandler(ch);
            register(logger.getName(), logger);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void register(String name, Logger logger) {
        MAP.putIfAbsent(name, logger);
    }

    public static Logger get(String name) {
        return MAP.get(name);
    }

    private static Logger loadFileLogger(String name, String path) throws IOException {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(name);
        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(path, true);
        fh.setFormatter(new ConsoleFormatter());
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        register(name, logger);
        return logger;
    }

    private static class ConsoleFormatter extends Formatter {
        @Override
        public synchronized String format(LogRecord record) {
            Date date = new Date();
            date.setTime(record.getMillis());
            String source;
            if (record.getSourceClassName() != null) {
                source = record.getSourceClassName();
                if (record.getSourceMethodName() != null) {
                    source += " " + record.getSourceMethodName();
                }
            } else {
                source = record.getLoggerName();
            }
            String message = formatMessage(record);
            String throwable = "";
            if (record.getThrown() != null) {
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                pw.println();
                record.getThrown().printStackTrace(pw);
                pw.close();
                throwable = sw.toString();
            }
            return String.format(FORMAT,
                    date,
                    source,
                    record.getLoggerName(),
                    "LOG",
                    message,
                    throwable);
        }
    }

}
```

The command I use to execute my shell script

```
exec /home/rscedit/run.sh
```

Edit: my data map is not only containing log files, but also other stuff like website files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your java program seems to be sensitive to working directory. Easiest solution I know, change this

```
java -jar -Xmx20480m /home/rscedit/Webserver.jar
```

to

```
(cd /home/rscedit ; java -jar -Xmx20480m Webserver.jar)
```

**Or**, change the Java, this (and everywhere you have the pattern)

```
loadFileLogger("ipn", "./data/log/ipn.log");
loadFileLogger("error", "./data/log/error.log");
```

to something like (to make it relative to `$HOME`),

```
loadFileLogger("ipn", new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), 
        "data/log/ipn.log").getPath());
loadFileLogger("error", new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), 
        "data/log/error.log").getPath());
```

Comment: Will this also work when linux tries to run my shell script in the background?

Comment: @Displee Yes. But I added another option; which is to make your paths relative to the `user.home` (instead of hardcoding relative paths).

Comment: I'd recommend to do it the way real log frameworks do - have a separate configuration file for those file paths & log definitions. Or if that's too much, just log to stdout/stderr and redirect those on startup.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, but you also need to locate the log configuration file in the data map, which ends into the same problem. My data map is containing more stuff like website files, not only logging files.